# Getting very low categorical_accuracy while refitting loaded Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm getting a very low `val_categorical_accuracy` on previously trained model. Steps I followed:

1. The model was trained for 30 epochs.
2. It achieved ~0.60 **val_categorical_accuracy** and categorical_accuracy.
3. It was saved using Kerases `model.save()` method.
4. On loading with `Keras.models.load_model()` and evaluating it, it returns accuracy on the right level. ~0.60

   ```
   from keras.models import load_model
   model = load_model(path)
   ```
5. While trying to refit the loaded model using `model.fit_generator()` of `model.fit()` the accuracy starts all over from the bottom ~0.01:

   ```
   Epoch 2/30 
   21537/21537 [==============================] - 4311s - loss: 5.6385 - 
   **categorical_accuracy: 0.0084** - val_loss: 5.6023 -         
   **val_categorical_accuracy: 0.0101**

   Epoch 3/30 
   21537/21537 [==============================] - 3477s - loss: 5.5899 -
   **categorical_accuracy: 0.0103** - val_loss: 5.5601 - 
   **val_categorical_accuracy: 0.0113**

   Epoch 4/30 
   21537/21537 [==============================] - 3475s - loss: 5.5542 - 
   **categorical_accuracy: 0.0117** - val_loss: 5.5154 - 
   **val_categorical_accuracy: 0.0125**
   ```

---

The model is a modified version of VGG16 with 2 Dense layers with `kernel_initializer='VarianceScaling'` which appeard to me as the only possibility to mess up the weights, but on loading models without it I faced the same problem.

- Optimizer : `SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)`
- ~/.keras/keras.json:

  ```
  {                                                                                                                                                            
   "epsilon": 1e-07,                                                                                                                                         
   "image_data_format": "channels_last", 
   "floatx": "float32", 
   "backend": "tensorflow" 
  }
  ```

**Is there something else i should do to load the model properly and re-train?**

### EDIT:

Found related issue on GitHub https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2378

Comment: Hi Marcel, your question seems valid (but triggered question review). Try to start the question with regular text instead of bullets. I was wondering ... how do you know that the model is not loaded properly... and that it needs re-training (keep in mind I'm not an expert on your subject). I assume you know what values to expect or to look for but that does not become clear for a non expert. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: @ZF007 Thank you for answering and the advice, i should've added some short explanation in the beggining indeed. I know that the model is loaded properly(see 4.) but i'm not sure about how exactly it is used in the training process (i thought it's going to start from the accuracy it was saved with).

Comment: Good to read it helps. Also your commented explanation will help others understand better what you exactly want. Add that to the question because it deepens your question ;-)

Comment: Marcel, are you using the `shuffle=False` option in `fit()`? If not, your model is training with a random initialization and will start from near-zero accuracy each time.

Comment: @economy no i'm not. Regarding the Keras docs the option shuffles batches before every epoch [see line 1544](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L1544)

Comment: @economy also here: [fit_generator()](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit_generator), [fit()](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit)

Comment: Marcel, the default is `shuffle=True`, try setting it to `False`.

Comment: See bottom LSTM example [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/), when setting `shuffle=False` the network becomes "stateful".

Comment: @economy, i did change it, but it doesn't resolve the issue. Please look at what i pasted in the comments above - the shuffle argument appears to be only responsible for **shuffling data** before starting new epoch and **not the weights**.

Comment: Are you sure that the categories are the same between runs? Maybe the order is changing each time you execute it...

Comment: @grovina i'm almost entirely sure that they are, but i'm going to double check it.

Comment: @grovina, the labels were the same but... they were loaded from a number of files and somehow the order of loading these files changed between every run of the script. Thank you very much for a good hint where to look for the problem! It works like a charm now.